# trim a string in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to trim a string to its first 100 characters using jquery/javascript.

also is it possible to scan a string and look for a particular combination of keywords such as #key?

thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To keep only the first 100 characters of a string use [substring](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp):

```
s = s.substring(0,100)
```

To search for a substring use [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_IndexOf.asp):

```
s.indexOf("#key")
```

Comment: +1, simple solution. `match` can also be used for searching: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, regular JavaScript will do just fine:

```
 var trimmed = MyString.substr(0, 100);
```

To your second, you can use regular expressions to scan for patterns: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html